# How to change UINavigationBar item image?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

How can I change my navigationBar item image on click on it? I'm trying this one:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.image = UIImage(named: "bookmark")
```

but it does not change/replace the image of the item. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a UIBarButtonItem and set it's image.

e.g.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "imageName"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "yourActionOrNil")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let infoImage = UIImage(named: "my-icon")    
let imgWidth = infoImage?.size.width    
let imgHeight = infoImage?.size.height    
let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: imgWidth!, height: imgHeight!))    
button.setBackgroundImage(infoImage, forState: .Normal)    
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("openInfo"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)    
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

=> `UIBarButtonItem(image:style:target:action:)` constructor only works for transparent PNG, also I had to set button tintcolor other than clearColor.